# Is there a simple example that empirical evidence is misleading?

Tags: undergraduate-education

Suppose that I want to show a student that empirical evidence in mathematics is not enough and we do need proofs, what kind of examples can I use?

By empirical evidence, I mean that (most of the time) you cannot simply check the statement $S(n)$ for $n \in \{1,\dots, 10^9\}$ and conclude it's true for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/15444/36173

Comment: If you pick $n$ (generic) points on a circle and connect them with lines, the disc divides into a number of regions. It appears to be a power of two for $n\leq 5$, then it changes. See the nice article: https://www.quantamagazine.org/where-proof-evidence-and-imagination-intersect-in-math-20190314/

Comment: A high school maths teacher gave "all numbers are less than a thousand, because one is less than a thousand, two is less than a thousand, etc. etc." as an example of bad empirical evidence.

Comment: I would like to point out this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186103/theorems-with-an-extraordinary-exception-or-a-small-number-of-sporadic-exception, in particular for the 'sausage catastrophe'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are some collections of such examples at sister sites:

- [Conjectures that have been disproved with extremely large counterexamples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514/conjectures-that-have-been-disproved-with-extremely-large-counterexamples)
   at Mathematics Stack Exchange.
- [Examples of eventual counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15444/36173) at MathOverflow.

---

One rather simple example that can be checked with a calculator is the conjecture by Fermat, that all numbers of the form $$2^{2^n}+1, \qquad n \in \mathbb N_0$$ are prime.

In fact,

- $2^{2^0} +1 = 3$ is prime
- $2^{2^1} +1 = 5$ is prime
- $2^{2^2} +1 = 17$ is prime
- $2^{2^3} +1 = 257$ is prime
- $2^{2^4} +1 = 65537$ is prime
- $2^{2^5} +1 = 4294967297$ is **not** prime: $4294967297 = 641 \cdot 6700417$

So the original conjecture is clearly false, but it took nearly 100 years to find the counterexample. All following Fermat numbers appear to be composite, but this is an open problem.

Comment: Yup, and if they think that example is "trivial", just mention _when_ it was proposed, disproved and how that compared with technology _of the time_. 4294967297 may not seem like a "big" number in the computer age, but it sure the hell was before then.

Comment: I strongly recommend answer #4 to the Mathematics Stack Exchange answer cited above. It requires no maths at all and anyone bar the thickest of students ought to get it! (#4 at time of commenting, more recs might change that -- is there any way to cite a particular answer n StackExchange? )

Comment: Why did it take nearly 100 years to come up with a counterexample when the counterexample is the fifth exponent (5) that a person tries. It's hard to imagine that no one tried with progressively larger exponents starting from 0 five times to see whether this conjecture was true at least five times, with easiest numbers available, 0 to 5. Are you essentially saying it took nearly a hundred years to find 4294967297 is not a prime number?

Comment: @nigel222 under each answer is a 'share' link (in grey text), click that and you get a popup containing a link to that specific answer.

Comment: @AakashM thanks! So I can now say I strongly recommend https://math.stackexchange.com/a/527/400776 cited above.

Comment: @Zebrafish : if you think it's easy, try calculating it yourself. Without a calculator. On a vellum. With a goose feather you have to dip into ink every few seconds.

Comment: @vsz, at night by candlelight.

Comment: Many years ago I calculated up to 2^127 by hand. Granted, this was in a well-lit room with pencil and paper, but I suspect those obstacles could be overcome by someone sufficiently dedicated (or bored). On the other hand, showing that it’s composite seems like it would be much harder.

Comment: @vsz While it's certainly a very monotonous task that would probably take a day or two for one person to accomplish, there have been much more arduous computations carried out by hand even in Fermat's time (for example [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140201234124/http://librarsi.comune.palermo.it/gesuiti2/06.04.01.pdf) contemporary book has over 190 pages of trigonometry tables)

Comment: @Zebrafish aside from Fermat nobody was seriously interested in number theory from the early 1600s until Euler came along around 100 years later.  Fermat was worried at the end of his life that his work would be forgotten. When an area of math is obscure (calling number theory an "area of math" in Fermat's time is too generous; Fermat just called it "numbers") and Fermat's letters were scattered around Europe, it's surprising that you'd think its surprising that nobody between Fermat and Euler would really care about testing primality of $2^{2^5}+1$.

Comment: I guess I was surprised there was only one guy in the 1600s seriously interested in number theory.

Comment: @Zebrafish Remember that prime factorization is one of the hardest problems in computation, which is why [etc.]

Comment: @vsz Using exponentiation by squaring, it's easy to show that $2^{32}$ is the same as $256^4$, which is $(256 \times 256)^2$. So you need to do two multiplications by hand: $256 \times 256$ to get 65536, then $65536 \times 65536$ to get the final 429496726.

Comment: You can read more of the story about $2^{32}+1$ in Weil's history of number theory book (section II.IV).  Apparently Fermat just didn't bother checking, even though he had a technique he had used to successfully factor a similar-sized Mersenne number.   Weil notes this technique is basically the same as the (modular arithmetic-based) one that Euler used later.  Anyway, by hand this was rather hopeless; see also Dunham's "Journey through Genius" for a perspective accessible to non-mathematicians.

Comment: @canton7 : that's the easiest part. But what about checking whether it's a prime? Yes, it is doable by hand, but still time-consuming.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Factorization is hardly "one of the hardest problems in computation." OK, we don't know any efficient algorithms for it, but there are plenty of harder problems. In fact, infinitely many, many of which are practically useful. (And, technically, we just need to know if it's prime, for which we now know a reasonably efficient algorithm.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hard means difficult. Factoring large primes without a computer is pretty damn difficult.

Answer (score 21):

Strangely, just this morning I asked [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20for%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20of%201%2F(n*sin(n))) to compute the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n\sin(n)}}$$ and it returned the approximate value of $-0.863507$. I asked it to "show more digits", and it returned a new approximation:

$-94.377284731050845020943145217217734512865979242824685504875914407196948018$

I was trying to illustrate a series for which convergence (or divergence) is difficult to determine and was treated to some very different approximations. Note that Wolfram did not tell whether the series converges.

Comment: FWIW: You can see in [MSE 665776](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665776) that the *sequence* $\frac{1}{n \sin(n)}$ does not converge; in particular, the sequence does not converge to $0$. So, the series described here does not converge.

Comment: Nice find. I knew I had seen a proof of that at one time, but I couldn't come up with an argument about how frequently n gets close to a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Among experts, it's well-known that WA gives lots of Wrong Answers for limit questions, sometimes claiming it converges when it actually diverges (as in your example) or vice versa, and it is trivial to generate such examples. So while I think your example is a great piece of evidence for not trusting WA (thanks for that!), it is not a good example of misleading empirical evidence since there is simply no empirical evidence to begin with...

Comment: @user21820 That would be a perfect reason to downvote this answer. Perhaps I should have just made it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Yea it's not an answer, but I didn't feel like downvoting or flagging because I think too few people know the truth about WA, and last time whenever I posted a counter-example on Math SE someone would go and tweak the algorithm simply to give the right answer to the counter-example, so I stopped posting counter-examples. I wouldn't be surprised if within a few months someone does that to yours too, but that's just too bad haha..

Answer (score 6):

There's a great paper out there called "The Strong Law of Small Numbers", by Richard K Guy, which provides numerous examples of misleading patterns. A PDF copy can be found here: https://www.ime.usp.br/~rbrito/docs/2322249.pdf

The YouTube channel "Numberphile" (if you aren't already a subscriber, which you should be) has a video by the same name that's also worth a look. It's where I first learned about the paper.

On a personal note, I remember stumbling across Guy's Example 8 myself in a different form (very simply: construct a list starting with 0, ending with 1, and containing all unique fractions between the two where the denominator is $\leq n$. Now count the members of the list. You'll find that $n=1$ produces $2$, $n=2\rightarrow3$, $n=3\rightarrow5$, $n=4\rightarrow7...$) The sense of being on to something weird and exciting and possibly new, then suddenly seeing it all fall apart was something I'll never forget. Finding out it had been written up in a paper twenty-plus years ago was the cherry on the sundae, for sure.

Answer (score 5):

There is an old joke describing how various scientific disciplines "prove" that all odd numbers are prime. The part for mathematicians goes

> 1 is a special case, 3 is prime, 5 is prime, 7 is prime, the proof by induction is left to the reader.

Comment: That's silly. The old Engineer, Physicist, Mathematician joke about black sheep in Scotland is much better. (Punchline: Mathematician: "Gentlemen, all we know is that in the whole of Scotland, there exists one sheep, one side of which is black").

Comment: @nigel222, *at least* one sheep, *at least* one side

Comment: @nigel222, the physicist would go "3 is prime, 5 is prime, 7 is prime, instrument error, 11 is prime, 13 is prime." The programmer says "1 is prime, 1 is prime, 1 is prime, ..."

Comment: This should be a  comment.

Comment: @Paracosmiste, why? It is an **extremely** simple example. It works for 3 steps to fail at the 4th.

Comment: @o.m. "you cannot simply check the statement $S(n)$ for $n \in \{1,\dots, 10^9\}$ and conclude it's true for all $n \in \mathbb N$".

Comment: @Paracosmiste, the accepted answer fails at n=5, so the OP obviously did not only want examples which fail in the billions.

Comment: @o.m. The accepted answer gives 2 links to such counterexamples. The example $2^{2^5} +1 = 4294967297$ doesn't satisfy the $10^9$ criteria but at least it's not trivial even with a calculator. What you wrote is an old joke not an answer. You can post it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist) maybe. Anyway let the OP decide.

Comment: @o.m. : in political science: "3 is prime, 5 is prime, 7 is prime, 9 will be prime next year, we promise!", in biochemistry: "let's take a look at 4861. It's odd, and... and it's a prime! Our experiment was successful!", in gender studies: "How dare you make differences between numbers! All numbers are equal!"

Comment: Engineers: 3 is prime, 5 is prime, 7 is prime, 9 is experimental error, 11 is prime, 13 is prime... All odd numbers are prime

Answer (score 5):

The [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test may be a good example.  It identifies "industrial strength primes," numbers which are strongly indicated to be prime through testing, but have not actually been proven to be prime.  It is based off of the proof that $a^d \equiv 1 (mod\;p)$ for all prime numbers.  The test flips that around into its contrapositive, and explores the idea that if we look for an $a$ which does not satisfy that equation, then we have found a "witness" which shows that $p$ is not prime.  It can be shown that all composite numbers have at least one witness, but a simple algorithm for determining it has never been found.  Instead, we test many $a$ and, if we find no witnesses, then we say $p$ is an "industrual strength prime" because we took a good swing at it and failed to disprove its primality.

As it turns out, testing small values of a is *enormously* successful.  So successful that you might make the assumption that testing just $a=2$ and $a=3$ is sufficient to prove a number is prime.  And you'd be right, so long as the number is smaller than 1,373,653, which is the first point where that test suggests a composite number is prime.

Maple's `isprime()` function relies on this test.  It tests $a=2$, $a=3$, $a=5$, $a=7$, and $a=11$.  This turns out to be a very fast and enormously effective test.  But there are numbers which fail this.  In fact, one mathematician identified a particular 397-bit number which passes all tests from $a=2$ through $a=307$, and yet is composite.

Comment: The significance of the Miller--Rabin test is *not* that each composite odd $n > 1$ has at least one witness for this test, but that it has a *lot* of witnesses for this test: at least 75 percent of integers from 1 to $n-1$ are witnesses to the compositeness of $n$ in the Miller--Rabin test.  Fermat's little theorem as a compositeness test (is $a^{n-1} \not\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for some $a$ from 1 to $n-1$?) has at least one witness when $n$ is composite, such as any factor of $n$ strictly between $1$ and $n-1$, but this does not make the Fermat test a good example because of Carmichael numbers.

Comment: A simple algorithm for making the Miller--Rabin test deterministic has been known since the 1980s if you assume GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions: an odd $n > 1$ is prime if and only if it has no witness for the Miller--Rabin test among the positive integers up to $2(\log n)^2$ (or $3(\log n)^2$, depending on how the test is described).

Comment: It's a pity your answer has so few upvotes, when it is such a good example.

Answer (score 5):

There is a classic undergrad example (apparently going back to Euler) still missing in this list:

$$n^2+n+41 \text{ is prime}$$

which is true for all $n<40$ but fails at $n=40$.

Answer (score 5):

The Yule-Simpson paradox or effect.  It is an important result in statistics that says you cannot simply plug numbers into a statistical engine and pop out a meaningful answer.

[image]

In this example, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox), the regression line is the dashed line.  It looks like there is a decreasing effect.  The true effect is that there is some categorical variable and in both possible states, the effect is an increasing one.

The famous example, which is in the Wiki article, is the UC Berkley case where there was apparent and substantial discrimination against women for admission.  What was found was that there was a small, but statistically significant bias for women over men once the academic department was controlled for.

It requires a person to think about subpopulations as well as the total population.  The danger is that simple analysis of the data is very misleading.  The mathematical intuition should be that if every subpopulation is increasing, the population should be increasing, but that is *not* true.

Think of that from a policy or voting perspective.  If society is worse off for each increase in $x$, then society should suppress $x$.  However, if every subpopulation is improved by $x$ increasing, then $x$ should be amplified.  In the graphic above, the actual intuition should not be about suppressing $x$ but about shifting the subpopulation represented by the red line to the left.  It would be even better to shift all subpopulations to the left, while amplifying $x$ at the same time.  It is the intercept that is the secret story in this diagram.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a straightforward example that knowing the first $k$ terms (no matter how big $k$ is) of a sequence $(x_n)$ tells you very little about the term $x_{k+1}$: I can generate a sequence whose first $k$ terms are $1,2,\dots,k$ but whose $(k+1)^{{\rm st}}$ term is an arbitrary $m$ of my choosing.  For the given $k$, let $x_n = n + \frac {m-n}{k!}(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k)$.

Now, for any $n$ up to $k$, a factor in the product is $0$, forcing the entire product to be $0$, leaving $x_n=n$.  Meanwhile, at $n=k+1$, the product $(k+1-1)\dots(k+1-k)=k!$, and straightforward arithmetic shows $x_{k+1}=m$.

Much more in fact is true.  Linear algebra can be used to show, given completely arbitrary first terms $a_1,\dots,a_{k+1}\in\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ for which $x_1=a_1,\dots,x_{k+1}=a_{k+1}$, and the generic term $x_n$ of $(x_n)$ is given as a polynomial in $n$ with degree at most $k$. (Indeed, the terms don't even need to be the ``first'' terms, we just need to know *which* terms they are.)

Without knowing something more about a sequence of real numbers than just ``these are some of the terms'', nothing of substance can be concluded about the sequence.

**Edit (30 May 2019):**  Many standardized tests have questions along the lines of ``If a sequence starts with the numbers $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, what is the next term in the sequence?" then proceeds to have a multiple choice answer, providing four numbers/answers.  One main point behind this example is that *all four answers are correct*.

Answer (score 3):

The Pell equation $x^2-Dy^2=1$ (where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers) admits solutions if the natural number $D$ is not a square number.  But for $D=61$ the smallest solution is astonishingly great: you can derive an example from this fact. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pell%27s_Equation/Examples/61

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to other fields that strongly rely on mathematics, you can use the [Rayleigh-Jeans catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe) as an example:

> The term "ultraviolet catastrophe" was first used in 1911 by Paul Ehrenfest, but the concept originated with the 1900 statistical derivation of the Rayleigh–Jeans law. The phrase refers to the fact that the Rayleigh–Jeans law accurately predicts experimental results at radiative frequencies below 105 GHz, but begins to diverge with empirical observations as these frequencies reach the ultraviolet region of the electromagnetic spectrum.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe) Since the first appearance of the term, it has also been used for other predictions of a similar nature, as in quantum electrodynamics and such cases as ultraviolet divergence.

The beginning times of quantum physics is full of such examples. This particular one was solved by Max Planck and physics has never been the same since then.

Answer (score 2):

Try representability by the sum of three cubes,
$$  x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = k  \text{.}  $$

Early computer search paper, that turned up no new representable $k$s.: Gardiner, V.L., R.B. Lazarus, and P.R. Stein, [Solutions of the Diophantine Equation $x^3 + y^3 = z^3 - d$](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1964-18-087/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9/S0025-5718-1964-0175843-9.pdf), 1964.  In this paper, no representations are found for $d = k = 30$ and $d = k = 33$ (and several more $d = k < 1000$).  Contains the lines "Nevertheless, it is in our opinion rather unlikely that all the missing $|d|$'s will turn out to be expressible as sums of three cubes.  It would be of interest to attempt a proof that, say, 30 cannot be so represented."

Recent paper:  Huisman, S., [Newer sums of three cubes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07746), 2016.  This paper finds that $33$ is the least $k$ with no known representation, so a representation for $k = 30$ was found in the interim.

Recent video: Haran, B. and A. Booker, [42 is the new 33 - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoz_NuIvP0), 12 March 2019.  A much larger empirical search found a representation for $k = 33$, leaving $k = 42$ as the least $k$ without a known representation.

Moral: empirical searches keep being inadequate.

Comment: Is the equation in your first paper's title equivalent to the equation above? It looks to me like some negative signs are required to group the three cubes (but not on all of them).

Comment: @jpmc26 : $(-x)^3 + (-y)^3 + z^3 = d$; $x$, $y$, and $z$ can absorb needed sign changes because the variables are not assumed positive.

Comment: @EricTowers In case you didn't know, the Sep. $6$, $2019$ ScienceDaily article [Sum of three cubes for 42 finally solved -- using real life planetary computer](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/09/190906134011.htm) says an answer for $42$ was finally found, but it "took over a million hours of calculating to prove". As such, the problem has now been solved for all $k$ from $1$ to $100$.

Answer (score 2):

[XKCD compiled a list of approximations](https://xkcd.com/1047/) several years back:

Many are just funny trivia, but you could use most of them as examples of the limits of empirical evidence, because empirical estimations using these formulas would seem to be strong evidence that they are correct, when mathematically they are complete nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep a running tally of primes of the form $4k+1$ vs $4k+3$, it seems like the latter are always at least as numerous. But it was eventually shown each type takes the lead infinitely many times; it's just you have to get into huge numbers before the first lead for $4k+1$.

Comment: However, after an early start, it is true that eventually both of these outnumber primes of the form $4k+2$.   I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition that this comment's character count is too narrow to contain.